# jQuery get multiple elements

Tags: jquery

Had a look at some of the other answers but none looked close to what Ive got so far.

I have a search function in WP that shows me a list of apartments with various meta. The purpose of this is so that a back end user can search for apartments they own, select each apartment they think is relevant to the clients needs and email the client a list of apartments. 
Each apartment has a containing div (.apartment-entry-container) and a check box inside to select the apartment for sending.

The user then adds name and email to a form before clicking send. This then should send all the data off to a function via ajax that emails he client. he email works fine, but the jQuery doesnt seem to be collecting all the selected divs and their content.

Basic HTML layout:

```
<div class="apartment-entry-container">                                     
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Some text</p>
                        <img src="animage">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="selectthis" id="selectthis">Select this appartment</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="apartment-entry-container">                                     
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Some text</p>
                        <img src="animage">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="selectthis" id="selectthis">Select this appartment</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="apartment-entry-container">                                     
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Some text</p>
                        <img src="animage">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="selectthis" id="selectthis">Select this appartment</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
jQuery('#search-query-send').click(function() {

  var name = jQuery('#name').val();       
  var email = jQuery('#email').val();

  jQuery('.selectthis input:checked').each(function() {
    content += jQuery(this).parents('.apartment-entry-container').html();
  });


  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://www.greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/citypads/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'action=apartmentsearchemail&email=' + email + '&content=' + content + '&name=' + name,
    success: function(result) {
      //got it back, now assign it to its fields.                     
      alert('Your message has been sent.');
      console.log(content);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate IDs for checkboxes. IDs should be always unique.

and the reason you do not have content is  because there is no elements input in element with class `selectthis`. you can rather find `.apartment-entry-container` that have input checked in it and then concatenate its html in contents:

```
var  content= "";
jQuery('.apartment-entry-container:has(input:checked)').each(function() {
  content += jQuery(this).html();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but your solutions is throwing me  a"content not defined" error

Comment: @AlexKnopp: thats because the variable was not defined. check the update

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. You have this:

```
 jQuery('.selectthis input:checked').each(function() {
```

And you need this:

```
 jQuery('input.selectthis:checked').each(function() {
```

It works.